# Undefined index: id

Tags: php, xampp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Okay, so I am trying to build my site and I am having a minor issue. I am getting errors like "Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 18" 
and
"Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 39"

I am certain it's a matter of syntax but I can't seem to find the right answer. Here is the php code in my index.php file on lines 16-18

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['logRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
```

The code worked before when I was running Apache 2 in linux. Now I am running Xampp on windows and all of a sudden it doesn't want to work right.

Whoever answers this, please write it in stupid. I'm still learning php. :) Thanks!

Comment: that's just a warning. it's not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a syntax error. You are trying to access a key that does not exist. It seems that warnings were disabled on your previous server.

Check if the actual variable is set (using [isset](http://php.net/isset)) before trying to access it:

```
if(
    isset($_SESSION['id']) &&
    !isset($_COOKIE['logRemember']) &&
    isset($_SESSION['rememberMe'] &&
    !$_SESSION['rememberMe']
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Still having some issues with the rest of the page. line 82: else if($_POST['submit']=='Register')

Answer (score 0):

You use `isset()` on the `$_COOKIE` variable, so you must know how that works for checking the existence of a variable. Just apply that to `$_SESSION['id']` and so on and the errors will stop.

Answer (score 0):

In your first run, `$_SESSION['id']` and `$_SESSION['rememberMe']` won't be set.
You have to check if they're set (just as you did with your cookie)

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !isset($_COOKIE['logRemember']) && !isset($_SESSION['rememberMe']))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it "worked" was because the Apache 2 server probably wasn't configured to display errors.  Your issue is that `$_SESSION['id']` isn't set.  Rather, check that it is with

```
isset($_SESSION['id'])
```

Which won't throw an error if it isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory where the session data is storred is writeable by apache. You can get the path by using `session_save_path ();`

Answer (score 0):

Replce line with following code

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !isset($_COOKIE['logRemember']) && !isset($_SESSION['rememberMe']))
```